# Smooth scrolling with just pure css

Tags: css

How can I make a smooth scrolling with just pure css.

I have this code [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dN4S4/)

**HTML**

```
<a id="up" href="#down">down</a>
<div class="up"></div>

<a id="down" href="#up">up</a>
<div class="down"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.up {
    width:100px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
}

.down {
    width:100px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I know `:target` can help but I don't know how to use it with `transition`.

Comment: I think the answers to this question and the one @sidney marked possible duplicate are vague on what "scrolling" is. The `transition` effect is only good for changing the positioning (NB: not scroll position) and so isn't really 'scrolling' as achieved with Skrollr or Jquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can* do this with pure CSS but you will need to hard code the offset scroll amounts, which may not be ideal should you be changing page content- or should dimensions of your content change on say window resize.

You're likely best placed to use e.g. jQuery, specifically:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
   scrollTop: element.offset().top
}, 1000);
```

A complete implementation may be:

```
$('#up, #down').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target= $(this).get(0).id == 'up' ? $('#down') : $('#up');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Where `element` is the target element to scroll to and `1000` is the delay in ms before completion.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/dN4S4/1/)

The benefit being, no matter what changes to your content dimensions, the function will not need to be altered.

Comment: thanks it works great at Fiddle but can you explain me this `scrollTop: element.offset().top`, why it is hust `top` or `scrollTop` ? I see no `down`.

Comment: In the fiddle, the function works out which of the two link elements has been clicked, then sets the `target` element to the opposite one, the page is the scrolled to the top of this `target`

Comment: But when we click on `down` we have to `scrollDown` not `scrollTop`.

Comment: The issue is semantic- it means scroll to the top of the passed element, it doesnt mean the direction of scroll

Comment: I try also this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dN4S4/2/) but i notice a strange behavior just after the click.

Comment: You need to do event.preventDefault() otherwise the browser is performing confliciting behaviour with the default anchor tag position change- copy the code in the answer

Comment: Yes right thanks a lot man but i didn't understand yet  `scrollTop: target.offset().top` i will think again myself and open a new question i don't get it.

Comment: The question asked for "just pure CSS" not JQuery...

Comment: @immx See the first line of the answer, and subsequent justification.

Answer (score 30):

You need to use the `target` selector.

Here is a fiddle with another example: http://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/

Comment: but it will be harder if i change the height of my DIVs.

Comment: You should do so, if you want pure css only.

Comment: Yes this is the price

Comment: That is a cool trick. I've never seen the `:target` pseudo-class before.